# UseEffect doesnt update buttons array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a BMI calculator app and I want it to change one of the 6 buttons from "btn-primary" to "btn-danger" colors depending on the BMI answer. but after calculation, no button changes color but the answer changes immediately.

Here is CalculationForm.js Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../stylesheets/calculation-form.css";
import Answer from "./Answer";

export default function CalculationForm() {
  const [weightVal, setWeightVal] = useState(0);
  const [heightVal, setHeightVal] = useState(0);

  const handleHeight = (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value;
    if (input.match(/^([0-9]{1,})?(\.)?([0-9]{1,})?$/)) {
      setHeightVal(input);
    }
  };

  const handleWeight = (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value;
    if (input.match(/^([0-9]{1,})?(\.)?([0-9]{1,})?$/)) {
      setWeightVal(input);
    }
  };

  let content;

  content = (
    <div className="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <form className="form">
        <div>
          <label>
            Weight (Kg): &nbsp;
            <input
              type=""
              value={weightVal}
              onChange={handleWeight}
              name="weight"
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Height (M): &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input
              type="text"
              value={heightVal}
              onChange={handleHeight}
              name="height"
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>

      <Answer weightVal={weightVal} heightVal={heightVal} />
    </div>
  );

  return <div className="container">{content}</div>;
}
```

Here is Answer.js component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../stylesheets/answer.css";

export default function Answer(props) {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    "btn-primary",
    "btn-primary",
    "btn-primary",
    "btn-primary",
    "btn-primary",
    "btn-primary",
  ]);

  let height = parseFloat(props.heightVal);
  let weight = parseFloat(props.weightVal);
  let answer = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);

  useEffect((answer) => {
    let newButtons = [
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
    ];

    if (answer < 18.5) {
      newButtons[0] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 18.5 && answer < 25) {
      newButtons[1] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 25 && answer < 30) {
      newButtons[2] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 30 && answer < 35) {
      newButtons[3] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 35 && answer < 40) {
      newButtons[4] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 40) {
      newButtons[5] = "btn-danger";
    }

    setButtons([...newButtons]);
  });

  return (
    <div className="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
      <p className="align-self-center h1 m-5">
        Your BMI is:{" "}
        {isNaN(answer) || !isFinite(answer) ? "Not measured" : answer}
      </p>

      <div className="btn-group d-flex flex-row">
        <button className={"btn " + buttons[0]}> Underweight</button>
        <button className={"btn " + buttons[1]}> Normal</button>
        <button className={"btn " + buttons[2]}> Overweight</button>
        <button className={"btn " + buttons[3]}>Class I obesity</button>
        <button className={"btn " + buttons[4]}>Class II obesity</button>
        <button className={"btn " + buttons[5]}>Class III obesity</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to pass buttons from CalculationForm.js component but I didn't find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `useState` and `useEffect` here. Create an array of static buttons, with their threshold values (`t`). Find the index of the 1st button that it's `t` value is greater then `answer`. Render the buttons using `Array.map()`, and set the `btn-danger` class to the button that matches the `dangerIndex`:

```js
const buttons = [
  { t: 18.5, txt: 'Underweight' },
  { t: 25, txt: 'Normal' },
  { t: 30, txt: 'Overweight' },
  { t: 35, txt: 'Class I obesity' },
  { t: 40, txt: 'Class II obesity' },
  { t: Infinity, txt: 'Class III obesity' },
]

function Answer({ heightVal, weightVal }) {
  const height = parseFloat(heightVal);
  const weight = parseFloat(weightVal);
  const answer = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
  
  const dangerIndex = buttons.findIndex(o => answer < o.t);

  return (
    <div className="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
      <p className="align-self-center h1 m-5">
        Your BMI is:{" "}
        {isNaN(answer) || !isFinite(answer) ? "Not measured" : answer}
      </p>

      <div className="btn-group d-flex flex-row">
        {buttons.map(({ txt }, i) => (
          <button key={txt}
            className={`btn ${i === dangerIndex ? 'btn-danger' : ''}`}>
            {txt}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Answer heightVal={1.6} weightVal={65} />)
```

```css
.btn-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let newButtons = [
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
      "btn-primary",
    ];

    if (answer < 18.5) {
      newButtons[0] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 18.5 && answer < 25) {
      newButtons[1] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 25 && answer < 30) {
      newButtons[2] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 30 && answer < 35) {
      newButtons[3] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 35 && answer < 40) {
      newButtons[4] = "btn-danger";
    } else if (answer >= 40) {
      newButtons[5] = "btn-danger";
    }

    setButtons([...newButtons]);
  }, [answer]);
```

Added a reliance array to the useEffect hook that includes the answer variable. This ensures that the effect only runs when the answer variable changes.